# Is solution of $\frac{dy}{dx}=x^2+y^2 +1$ an odd function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I had this question in my exam which is of multiple select question (MSQ) type. I am sure about three options but confused about one.
Question is "Let $(-c,c)$ be the largest open interval in $R$ ($c$ >0) on which the solution $y(x)$ of the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=x^2+y^2 +1$ with initial condition $y(0)=0$ exists and is unique. Then which of the is/are true?"
Options were
(A) $y(x)$ is an odd function on $(-c,c)$
(B) $y(x)$ is an even function on $(-c,c)$
(C) $(y(x))^2$ has a local minimum at $0$
(D) $(y(x))^2$ has a local maximum at $0$

Clearly $\frac{dy}{dx}>0$, so $y$ is strictly increasing. Given that $y(0)=0$, we then have $y(x)<0$ for $x<0$ and $y(x)>0$ for $x>0$. Using this, options (B) and (D) get discarded and option (C) looks correct. But not getting any idea about option (A). Also I tried to solve this ODE but no method is working that I know.

Any hint or help. Thanks.

Comment: What differential equation does $f(x)=y(-x)$ satisfy, and what are the initial conditions? What differential equation does $g(x)=-y(x)$ satisfy, and what are the initial conditions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use uniqueness. Let $z(x) := -y(-x)$. Then
$$ z'(x) = y'(-x) = x^2 + y(-x)^2 + 1 = x^2 + z^2(x) + 1 $$
as $z(0) = 0$, by uniqueness, $z = y$ and $y$ is odd.

Comment: Thank you Sir..

Comment: If a function is odd then its derivative is even. Can we say on this basis that solution of the differential equation  is odd.

Answer (score 3):

(C) is also correct. By implicit differentiation, $\frac12(y^2)' = yy' = y(x^2+y^2+1)$. So $\frac12(y^2)'' = y'(x^2+y^2+1) + y(2x+2yy')$. From this we deduce that $(y^2)' = 0$ at $x=0$ and $(y^2)'' = 1$ at $x=0$, and so $y^2$ has a local minimum at $0$.